# Log4Net inserting in SQL db not working

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, log4net

I have a problem with Log4Net. It doesn't add any entry in the table...
here is the table query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Log4Net_Error](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Thread] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Level] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Logger] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Message] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
[Exception] [varchar](2000) NULL
```

) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

and the code in the web.config is bellow:

```
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=pnawebloket;Integrated Security=True" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log4Net_Error2 ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
<!-- Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1 -->
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
</root>
```

Also, in global.asax.cs in Aplication_Start i added the line

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

And i still have no entry in the table.

```
public ActionResult Employees()
    {
        log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
        logger.Info("test");

        //throw new Exception("ex");
        ViewBag.Message = "Bellow is a table with employee's";
        var employees = employeerepository.FindAllEmployee().ToList();

        return View(employees);
    }
```

If i try to add the message in a text file work's fine.

App is in MVC3 and i'm using sql server 2008r2

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

Your Log table : Log4Net_Error ; Log Table at configuration file : Log4Net_Error2. You should change table name as Log4Net_Error at configuration file.